# Function call error Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm using https://repl.it/languages/scheme to compile my Scheme code and I'm running into some function call errors. The function is:

```
 (define (bloop x)
      (cond
        ((null? x) 0)
        ((not (list? (car x))) 
            (+ 1 (bloop (cdr x))))
        ((eq? x ’()) (bloop (car x)))))
```

I want to pass something like:

```
(bloop '((1) 2 3 4))
```

But I get:

```
Error: execute: unbound symbol: "’"
```

Any comment, question or concern is appreciated.

Comment: Couple of points of `bloop`: 1. `(null? x)` and `(eq? x '())` check the same thing; 2. `cond` in some (most?) Scheme implementations is required to have `else` clause. 3. What if `x` is a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line:

```
((eq? x ’()) (bloop (car x)))))
```

The `’` symbol is not ASCII quotation `'`.

PS. In Scheme jargon `bloop` is a *procedure*. *Function* is something mathematical, like "sin(x)", but `(sin x)` is a procedure implementing this function.

Comment: I see that Biwa Scheme uses "function" to mean "procedure". Heretics! :)